# Не загружается unity

Tags: unity3d, разработка-игр

Попытался обновить Unity, но так и не смог этого сделать. После чего, решил зайти в Unity Hub и открыть свой проект. В итоге вылезает ошибка

> Failed to start the Unity Package Manager local server process. Make sure the process [путь к файлу] is not blocked by Windows Defender or any other anti-virus configuration.
> Предлагают выбрать диагностику(Click on Diagnose to launch the Unity Package Manager Diagnostics tool) или перезапустить проект(Click to on Retry to relaunch Unity and reopen your project).

Ни то ни другое(я имею ввиду про кнопки) не срабатывает.

Пробовал инструкции такие, как:
отключить антивирус, брандмауэр, изменить правило в брандмауэр, запустить от имени администратора и многое другое, что есть на просторах необъятного...

Если, кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой проблемой, то как он смог её решить? Спасибо! [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Переустановка? Банально, но вдруг...

Comment: @Cordis сохраниться ли мой проект?

Comment: Да. Если хотите перестраховаться - просто скопируйте проект в другую папку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогает обычная переустановка Unity(а также Unity Hub, если вдруг проблема останется). Стоит отметить, что проекты(лично у меня), НЕ сохранились и удалились при переустановке. Поэтому стоит сделать резервное копирование вашего проекта, а именно:

1. Перейдите в папку, где установлена программа Unity(по стандарту, папка называется также).
2. Скопируйте папку с Вашим проектом(она называется так, как вы назвали
   проект, при создании) в любую другую папку.
3. Переустанавливаете Unity(если нужно, то и Unity Hub).
4. Устанавливаете нужную версию Unity(это делается в Unity Hub).
5. Копируете в папку Unity(она появится после установки нужной версии), Ваш проект. **Копировать нужно именно в папку Unity, а не в папку с названием версии.**
6. Открываете Unity Hub и открываете нужный проект.*

**Если Вы установили не правильную версию Unity, то Вам предложат установить нужную. Соглашаемся, ждем уставку, повторяем 6-ой шаг.*

Answer (score 1):

У меня была та же проблема! Пробовал:

1. Переустановку Unity
2. Настройку браундмауэра и антивируса

Всё дело оказалось в киррилице в названии папки проекта!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Было тоже самое, ну или почти. И так.

В названии папок по пути к проекту не должно быть *точек*, *Киллицы*, *запятых и тд*, - лучше просто **Английский**.
Убедись что в *Unity Hub --> preferences --> General --> Unity Editors folder*, установлен путь к Unity Editor.
Можно бонально попробовать переустановить Unity Hub и Unity versions.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте обновить драйвера видеокарты мне помогло.